HTTP Error 500 al iniciar aplicación en Yii2
Al momento de iniciar mi aplicacion de Yii2, la cargo en mi navegador de la siguiente manera http://localhost/basic/web/ y me sale el siguiente error: This page isn’t working, localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500.
Otro dato relevante podría ser que siempre que inicio XAMPP, Apache no inicia correctamente, por lo cual tengo que usar un comando adicional:
wguia03@wguia03-Aspire-A515-52G:/var/log/apache2$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.2.12-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
wguia03@wguia03-Aspire-A515-52G:/var/log/apache2$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
wguia03@wguia03-Aspire-A515-52G:/var/log/apache2$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.2.12-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.

Además he revisado el archivo error.log en el directorio /var/log/apache2 para ver que sucede desde el encendido de la pc, pero creo que no hay información relevante:
[Sat Apr 20 11:17:31.145039 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1092:tid 131122244540288] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 20 11:17:31.146370 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1092:tid 131122244540288] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Apr 20 11:21:08.138138 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1092:tid 131122244540288] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

Estoy usando XAMPP 8.2 y PHP 8.1.2 (php-cli) ambos funcionando correctamente en Ubuntu 22.04

Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Verifica en el log de errores de apache, hay debe estar el error especifico que provoca el error 500.

@FranciscoNuñezIALover He revisado el archivo error.log en el directorio /var/log/apache2 pero creo que no hay información relevante. Lo que si me parece extraño es que cada vez que inicio XAMPP, Apache no inicia correctamente, por lo cual tengo que usar un comando adicional. Dejaré la información adicional en la pregunta.

ese log es despues del reinicio ... debe haber uno error.log.1 ooooo cuando entres y te salga nuevamente el error 500 debe haber otro log llamado access.log en donde puede tambien verce que esta pasando ...

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Ya pude solucionarlo. El error se encontraba al instalar yii2 con composer. Necesitaba habilitar algunas extensiones de PHP para que pueda funcionar. Gracias por tu tiempo amigo.

El error se encontraba al instalar yii2 con composer: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Necesitaba habilitar algunas extensiones de PHP para su funcionamiento. Luego de eso todo funciona correctamente.
